# Does it delete partially if execute a delete statement without transaction?

Tags: sql

If the table myTable contains 100000000 records.

And I execute `DELETE FROM myTable;` without begin transaction and somethings go wrong, such as server power failure.

Will it delete some of the records?

Comment: So, Do I need begin transaction if execute a single DELETE statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, if the DB engine conforms to [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Any single write action is *Atomic*, whether contained in an explicit transaction or not.

A.k.a. each write action is a self contained transaction.

Answer (score 3):

I would say no it will not delete partial, but without knowing the database server you use it's hard to tell.